# osPathSeparator is of type rune but want to use as a string

Tags: go

I am currently using `strings.TrimLeft(s string, cutset string)` on a path and want to pass `os.PathSeparator` as the second argument.

`os.PathSeparator` is defined in the `os` package as follows:

```
const (
    PathSeparator     = '\\' // OS-specific path separator
    PathListSeparator = ';'  // OS-specific path list separator
)
```

When I do pass it, I get the following error:

> cannot use os.PathSeparator (type rune) as type string in argument to strings.TrimLeft

Any idea why `os.PathSeparator` isn't a string?

Comment: Because it is not a string but a single character?

Comment: @Volker having spent the past year purely coding in Python, it will take me a while to adjust back to statically types languages

Comment: It's a fair question, I think. I'm not sure I've ever had a use for a path separator where I wasn't appending/joining it with strings. So I would question its usefulness as anything other than a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the separator actually is only a single character. If you want to use it as a string, why not simply cast it to string?

```
strings.TrimLeft("/absolute/path", string(os.PathSeparator))
```

will return `"absolute/path"`

Answer (score 1):

Path separators are single characters. If a given constant fits in a type, there's little reason to use a broader type.

You can still trim using `os.PathSeparator`, you just need to make a string out of it first.

For instance:

```
fmt.Println(strings.TrimLeft("/foo/bar/baz", string(os.PathSeparator)))
// Outputs: foo/bar/baz
```